# Use correct background color for Chrome extension devtools panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In my Chrome extension, I'm adding a panel to the Developer tools window. By default, the background of my html panel page is white, but I want it to show the correct background color when user switches to dark theme.

I can query the current theme via the `chrome.devtools.panels.themeName` property, but from there I don't know what the right color code to use for the background if the current theme is the dark theme. The background of the developer tools window is some shade of black. I know it's not 'black'.

Comment: Get that color using a color picker and use it when the theme is dark.

Comment: That's not an ideal solution. The color may be different for different browsers and on different OSes.

Comment: There's no other solution.